# On CentOS how do I get boost header files installed?

Tags: yum, centos6, boost

What CentOS 6 package name do I need to install boost header files:

`yum install boost` doesn't seem to work. Is there a special compiler directive I need to use to point to the include files? Or is there another package to install?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good method of checking if the header files are available in a package (CentOS or RHEL):
`yum search $PROGNAME | grep dev`.

Answer (score 9):

Figured it out:

`yum install boost-devel`

Comment: How did you link to the files after installation?